# Shiny horizontal sortable rank_list

Tags: r, shiny, sortablejs

Is there a way to have an inline/horizontal `rank_list` from the `sortable` package?

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rank_list(labels = c("/", "26", "2022", "August", "/"), 
            input_id = "rank")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Gives:

[image]

But I would like to have the labels horizontal and slide horizontally over one another to construct a more readable date.

I tried `rank_list(..., options = sortable_options(direction = "horizontal"))` and also `"vertical"` but neither made a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(
    div(
        style = "width: 500px", id = "my-ranklist",
        rank_list(labels = c("/", "26", "2022", "August", "/"), 
                  input_id = "rank"),
        tags$style(HTML(
            '
            #my-ranklist .rank-list {
                display: flex;
            }
            #my-ranklist .rank-list-item {
                width: 100px;
            }
            '
        ))
    )

    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Change `500px` for the whole container and `100px` for each item to the width you want.

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you! Do you mind expanding on this slightly to show how this might work in `renderUI`? The `labels` are going to be reactive. I can update my post if that is helpful.

Comment: @LMc this is just CSS, so there will not be any big change with `renderUI`, but yes update the post and I will see if I understand your question.

Comment: Nevermind that worked perfect in `renderUI`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have any advice on what `direction` does in the `option` argument?

Comment: It's working in the original JS library but not in Shiny. I think Shiny people introduced a bug here. See this https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#example7