# Renaming and sorting columns of a dataset using the sortable package in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, jquery-ui-sortable

I have been following the solution provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75977503/synchronizing-column-order-between-two-rhandsontable-outputs-in-a-shiny-app) to update the names and column order of a dataset in a Shiny app. The original solution used a dummy dataset, but now I want to extend this solution to for a dataset (e.g., uploaded by the user) with an unknown number of columns in advance. How can I achieve this?

This is what I have tried so far:

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(width = 3, uiOutput('ui_rank_list')),
           column(width = 9, 
                  actionButton('gen_test_data', label = 'Generate test data'),
                  tableOutput('preview_table')))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv_data <- reactiveVal()
  
  # Generate some test data
  observeEvent(input$gen_test_data, {
    nrows <- 5
    ncols <- sample(2:10, 1) # This number is in fact unknown
    col_names <- replicate(ncols,
                           paste0(c(sample(letters, 4, replace = TRUE),
                                    sample(10:100, 2, replace = TRUE)), collapse = ''))
    DT <- data.table(matrix(1:(5*ncols), ncol = ncols))
    setnames(DT, col_names)

    rv_data(DT)
  })
  
  # Generate UI for selecting data set as well as buttons
  output$ui_rank_list <- renderUI({
    req(rv_data(), rv_labels())
    
    DT <- copy(rv_data())
    inputIds <<- paste0("textInput", seq_along(names(DT)))
    labels <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(initial_column_names), function(i){textInput(inputId = inputIds[i], label = "", value = initial_column_names[i], width = NULL, placeholder = NULL)}), inputIds)
    
    column_rank_list <- rank_list(
      text = "Reorder / rename columns",
      labels = labels,
      input_id = "column_rank_list"
    )
    column_rank_list
  })
  
  # Change columns' order
  observeEvent(input$column_rank_list, {
    req(input$column_rank_list)
    tmpDT <- copy(rv_data())
    column_order <- sapply(input$column_rank_list, function(x){ input[[x]] })
    setcolorder(tmpDT, column_order)
    rv_data(tmpDT)
  })
  
  # Change column names
  observeEvent(sapply(inputIds, function(x){input[[x]]}), {
    req(input$column_rank_list)
    tmpDT <- copy(rv_data())
    column_order <- sapply(input$column_rank_list, function(x){ input[[x]] })
    setnames(tmpDT, column_order)
    rv_data(tmpDT)
  })
  
  # Preview table
  output$preview_table <- renderTable({
    req(rv_data())
    rv_data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I return the following error: `Error in lapply: object 'inputIds' not found`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you didn't put the parentheses there,
in # Generate UI for selecting data set as well as buttons:

replace this

```
labels <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(initial_column_names), function(i){textInput(inputId = inputIds[i], label = "", value = initial_column_names[i], width = NULL, placeholder = NULL)}), inputIds)
```

to

```
labels <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(initial_column_names), function(i) {
  textInput(
    inputId = inputIds[i],
    label = "",
    value = initial_column_names[i],
    width = NULL,
    placeholder = NULL
  )
}, inputIds))
```

To solve such problems, you should consider “Debugging”,
for example, by [this](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html).

And you shouldn't use global variables at all, because it makes the code, for example, [unpredictable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).

In general, package [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/index.html) with functions
[`rename()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/base.html?q=rename#rename-rename-variables-by-name),
[`relocate()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/relocate.html)
and
[`tidy select`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html)
can be used to manipulate a data frame.